# This operation is not supported for a relative URI

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I have an hyperlink that throw the exception :
"This operation is not supported for a relative URI"

Code:

```
 Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsolutePath);
```

I want to enforce it to open the browser even if the uri is something like : "1aabbb3"

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore");` should open a very specific browser to it's home page.

Comment: Abrahams - Thanks , but how can I open it with my url (even that my url is garbage)

Comment: @Erez, the code above would launch the browser. If you don't have a proper URL where are you expecting to navigate?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Uri.OriginalString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring.aspx)

```
 Process.Start("iexplore.exe", e.Uri.OriginalString);
```

Edited to reflect clarification in comment.

Comment: I tried it but it throw "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: ahh I thought you wanted the process to be started identified by the URL, if you wanted to open a new browser with that URL just use Noel's Process.Start and pass it the URL as parameter, i.e. Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");

Answer (score 0):

Solution1: check IsAbsoluteUri and use OriginalString

```
        if (uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
            Console.WriteLine("Url:{0}", uri.AbsoluteUri);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Url:{0}", uri.OriginalString);
```

Solution2: define the url protocol

```
        url = "http://someRelativeUrl";
        uri = new Uri(url);
        Console.WriteLine("Url:{0}", uri.AbsoluteUri);
```